# Many different classes in @return. How to avoid writing them all?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a function:

```
$model = $this->model('aNameOfTheModel');
```

Is there another method of PHPDocing the `model()` than this one:

```
/**
 * @return A|B|C|D|E|F model(string $name)
 */
```

A, B, C... classes have different methods (for example `A::getMaleUsers` or `B::whenPartyStarts`). I would like to avoid writing all the A, B, C... in `@return`.

Comment: Do they share a common supertype? If not, you may be stuck with `mixed`.

Comment: They all differs from each other. Putting `mixed` will turn off suggestions in IDE.

Comment: My kingdom for overloading.

Comment: The only solution to preserve suggestions is to put `/** @var $model A */` above the `$model`. Which is painful.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would define a `model()` function inside of each class. Then you would call that class's model function. (Also usually model functions are static, as they instantiate the object as a singleton but I guess this all depends on what you're doing)

Then you can PHPDoc each class individually, and run the same underlying code by just extending the class with the parent model function in it. Then the model method inside of each class might look something like this:

```
class foo extends bar {

  /** @return foo */
  public static function model()
  {
    return parent::model('foo');
  }

}
```

Then in the class your extending you have a model function like so:

```
class bar {

  public static function model($className)
  {
    //todo: code for whatever you do to get your model class object
    return $model
  }

}
```

Comment: In my case `model()` is a `Kernel` method, which bootstraps database (if it is the first `model()` call) and than creates model. So, unfortunately I cannot implement your suggestion.